# Bluetooth low energy (BTLE) device support

Tags: android, ios, mobile, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Do all devices that support Bluetooth 4.0 or higher have Bluetooth low energy capabilities?

Wikipedia states that Bluetooth low energy is also known as Bluetooth Smart and that Bluetooth Smart was integrated into the main Bluetooth standard in 2010 with the adaptation of the Bluetooth Core Specification Version 4.0.

For example, the Sony Xperia E5 states it supports the following Bluetooth technologies: v4.1, A2DP, aptX. It does not state specifically anything about BTLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes
Bluetooth 4.0+ is also called Bluetooth Low Energy or Bluetooth Smart - you can find more information [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/what-is-bluetooth-technology/bluetooth-technology-basics/low-energy)

So if your phone supports BT 4.1 it also supports BLE

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not mandatory to implement Bluetooth Low Energy in Bluetooth 4.0 and higher, but most bluetooth controllers do.